# C# string with decimal into formatted int

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm looking to try to change a string like `10.00%` into an int like `1000`.

I've been trying different things but I keep getting FormatException errors.

Here's what I've done to work around it:

```
string text = "10.00%"; 
string s = text.TrimEnd(new char[] {'%'});
float f = float.Parse (s);
int i = (int)f;
i = i*100;
```

Is there a better way?

Per comment - for `10.10%` and `12.345%` I would want the results of `1010` and `12345`

However, for my uses, I would never parse `12.345%` as it wouldn't exist in my string value, instead it would be `12.34%`

always 2 decimals

Comment: What result do you expect for the `"10.10%"` input? And for `"12.345%"`?

Comment: what about replace % and . with empty char?

Comment: You can try regex if you want to remove all characters except digits. Regex.Replace(text, "[^0-9]", "")

Comment: @zerkms for those I would want what my algorithm produces "1010" and "12345"

Comment: Are you sure it should be `12345` not `1234` or `1235`?

Comment: @zerkms added more details to my question

Comment: why am i getting downvotes?

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer why won't my answer work? may I know?

Comment: @CodingYoshi I didn't downvote you, some people are just rude on here and don't care to provide feedback, but your solution looks like JavaScript and also needlessly complicates what I'm asking for

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer no it is not javascript and it does not needlessly complicate anything. That is the minimum you need to do. See my edit.

Comment: @CodingYoshi thanks, i'm still new to C# thought `var` was JS only keyword, more on that in your answer comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
var possibleNum = text.Replace(".", "").Replace("%","");
int num;
If(int.TryParse(possibleNum, out num) 
{
     // it's an int and the value is in num
} 
else
{
    // not int so what do you want to do
}
```

**EDIT**

In the comments the OP said the string will always be parse-able to a number, so in that case, just do this:

```
int num = int.Parse(text.Replace(".", "").Replace("%",""));
```

Comment: appreciate your input, does `var` auto parse into `int`? i need to use this value in `Random.Range()` and want the version where it uses `int` because it does not include the max value

Comment: yes `var` will take the type from the first value assigned to it on the right (in this case an int) and it will be an `int` afterwards. You can use `int` instead if you want.

Answer (score 1):

For accuracy with the math I would keep it as a float but here's a tad simpler solution

```
string t = "10.00%";
float f = float.Parse(t.Split('%')[0]);
int i = (int)(f * 100);
```

What I would do is

```
string t = "10.00%";
float f = float.Parse(t.Split('%')[0]);
f = f * 100;
```

Comment: thanks, looks like just a bit of a line saver, I'll work with this, I'm wanting `int` specifically for use in `Random.Range()` because I don't want the max value included

Comment: Sorry about the syntactical error, you could probably one line the int deceleration if you wanted to with ```int num = (int)(float.Parse(t.Split('%')[0]) * 100);``` maybe, sorry for any errors just typing it up fast.